# Get around API authentication and keys (like Facebook and Twitter)

Tags: python, facebook, api, twitter

I'm trying to make a kind of robot in Python, scanning some information on the internet I chose. The problem is that some websites like Facebook and Twitter got API demanding keys at each use.
For example, how can I find Twitter results to a research without weird keys to validate my request in Python ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to authenticate for each API, then the route to take is to **scrape**. Basically, you would download the [twitter search results](https://twitter.com/search?q=beautifulsoup&src=typd) in HTML form and the parse that HTML file. If you view the HTML file (`control + U` in firefox), you can see the tweet text is contained in this element:

```
<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">
```

You won't be able to collect as much data, but it will be *mostly* anonymously collected (without a key/authentication). To collect more data, you can **crawl** using links you find in the website HTML (i.e. *next page*).

Here is some reading material on scraping in python: [link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/).

In additional to [lxml](http://lxml.de/), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a powerful and popular library for scraping and parsing HTML.